# getting user defined error messages using antlr3

Tags: antlr, message

```
numberrange returns [String value]
    :   numberrangesub
        {
        String numberRange = ($numberrangesub.text);
        String [] v = numberRange.split(",");
        if ( Integer.parseInt(v[0].trim()) < Integer.parseInt(v[1].trim())) $value =numberRange;
        else throw new RecognitionException();
        }
    ;
```

Please observe the above ANTLR code. In this I want to throw a user friendly error message like `"from value should be less than to value in BETWEEN clause"`. 
I am expecting like this `RecognitionException("from value should be less than to value in BETWEEN clause");` But antlr did not accept like as above.

In java class where I am calling the generated java class by Antlr. I am handling like as follows.

```
try
{
    parser.numberRangeCheck();
}
catch (RecognitionException e)
{
    throw createException("Invalid Business logic syntax at  " + parser.getErrorHeader(e) + ", " + parser.getErrorMessage(e, null), Level.INFO, logger);
}
```

Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: Could you use the code formatter on the ANTLR code? That would make it much easier to read.

Comment: numberrange returns [String value]
    :   numberrangesub
        {
        String numberRange = ($numberrangesub.text);
        String [] v = numberRange.split(",");
        if ( Integer.parseInt(v[0].trim()) < Integer.parseInt(v[1].trim())) $value =numberRange;
        else throw new RecognitionException();
        }
    ;

Comment: I am using the code formatter but it is appearing unformatted after i posted it.I dont know why it is happening?

Comment: make sure you have 4 spaces before all code and that there is one line break after the code and your text.

Comment: numberrange returns [String value] : numberrangesub { 
    
    String numberRange = ($numberrangesub.text); 

    String [] v = numberRange.split(",");

    if ( Integer.parseInt(v[0].trim()) < Integer.parseInt(v[1].trim())) $value =numberRange;     
    else throw new RecognitionException(); } ;

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply throw a `RuntimeException` with your custom error message?

```
// ...
else throw new RuntimeException("from value should be less than to value in BETWEEN clause");
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

As Terrance wrote in "*The Deﬁnitive ANTLR Reference*" [error chapter excerpt](http://media.pragprog.com/titles/tpantlr/errors.pdf):

> To avoid forcing English-only error messages and to generally make
>   things as ﬂexible as possible, the recognizer does not create exception
>   objects with string messages. Instead, it tracks the information necessary to generate an error.

So there is no error message supplied to `RecognitionError`'s constructor. But you can define additional field of your recognizer to hold user-friendly error message shown on `RecognitionError` handling:

```java
numberrange returns [String value]
    :   numberrangesub
        {

        String numberRange = ($numberrangesub.text);
        String [] v = numberRange.split(",");
        if ( Integer.parseInt(v[0].trim()) < Integer.parseInt(v[1].trim()))
            $value = numberRange;
        else {
            this.errorMessage = "from value should be less than to value in BETWEEN clause";
            throw new RecognitionException(this.input);
        }

        }
    ;
```

And then override the `getErrorMessage` method:

```java
public String getErrorMessage(RecognitionException e, String[] tokenNames) {
    String msg = this.errorMessage;
    // ...
}
```

This works similar to paraphrase mechanism explained in the same excerpt.